# navbar not working in mobile web app

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple nabber with page-scroll. It works in the desktop but when I view it in the mobile web app, it doesn't even display the menu or the toggle navigation. I am sure I am missing something with respect to mobile view but not sure. I checked couple of posts from stack overflow but didn't help. Please refer the navbar code snippet below

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"
style="background-color: #757470; padding-left: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 64px;">
<div class="container" id="menu">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
        id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
        style="font-family: Lato; font-size: 12px;" class="gatewayNav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav"
            style="padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">
            <li><div style="" class="gatewayLogo"></div>
                <h1 style="padding-left: 200px;"></h1></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home"
                id="homeMenu" prevent-default="" scroll-to="home"
                style="border: medium none; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px;"><b
                    style="color: white; font-size: 13px;">HOME</b><br> </a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#startups"
                prevent-default="" scroll-to="startups"
                style="border: medium none; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; color: white;"
                id="startupMenu"><b style="color: white; font-size: 13px;">STARTUPS</b>
                    <br> </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that you are loading jquery first and then bootstrap's javascript after that.  If you have these loaded correctly then your problem may be a couple of different issues.  One being that if you are not seeing the toggle button you may have some custom css for your toggle button making it have no border or something to that effect.  And without the `<span class="icon-bar"></span>` elements in the button you may not be seeing the toggle button.  Next thing I see is you have a height set for the navbar.  If you are seeing the toggle button and after clicking on it you don't see the dropdown because you have a white page.  You may want to consider adding padding to get your desired height instead of giving it a height.

Here is a fiddle with your navbar working.  I added a top and bottom padding of 7px because bootstrap 3's navbars are 50px so to get to 64px you can just add 7 to the top and bottom.  Then I added the icon bars to the toggle button so you can see it.  Like I said though make sure you loaded jquery first then bootstraps js file after as well.  Here is the fiddle demo [JsFiddle Navbar Fix](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/vo0xa821/)

PS if you are not going to have a dropdown menu for each of your `<li>` elements in your navbar then there is no reason to add the dropdown class to the `<li>`.  Also are you going to be toggling a tab or scrolling to a section when you click on your links and all of the page breaks and strange paddings may be causing some issues.  Please leave a comment after this answer so I can understand what you are trying to achieve with all of this because it looks like you have a lot of conflicting issues with this entire markup and I am just trying to understand what you are trying to do so maybe I can help.

Comment: Thanks, this guidance was helpful. Actually I had to add the missing <span class="icon-bar"></span> and then remove an additional css library (android-bootcards) that was hiding this to be displayed. 

After adding the span and removing this reference, it worked the way I needed

THanks again